# Laravel - Get an user who has specific relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a user with countries relationship. (hasMany)

```
user_id 1
country_id 1

user_id 1
country_id 2

...
```

What I want is to get those users who have both countries (country 1 and country 2) How can I do this? I'm reading http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations but I'm not very sure what to do.

edit: almost the solution

```
$users = \User::whereHas('countries', function($query) {
    $countries_ids = [1, 2, 4];
    $query->whereIn('users_countries.country_id', $countries);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work as long as there are no duplicates in the pivot table (unique index for pair of fk keys for example):

```
$countries = [1,5,9];

User::whereHas('countries', function ($q) use ($countries) {
  $q->whereIn('users_countries.country_id', $countries);
}, '=', count($countries) )->get();
```

---

In case there are duplicates, like:

```
user_id | country_id
   1    |     1
   1    |     2
   1    |     1
```

Then you would need raw `count(distinct ...)` so you couldn't use `whereHas`, so I suggest this, which will be much faster:

```
$countries = [1,5,9];

User::join('users_countries as uc','uc.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
  ->whereIn('uc.country_id', $countries)
  ->having(DB::raw('count(distinct uc.country_id)'), '=', count($countries))
  ->groupBy('users.id')
  ->get(['users.*']);
```

Comment: Very nice! I'd tried only the first one because I have no duplicates. Thx.

Comment: You're welcome. 2nd solution is far better in terms of performance though - there are no dependant queries etc

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk can you help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474941/how-to-get-the-max-id-in-a-join-query-in-laravel-5-integrity-constraint-violati

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way. Make the query on the country model. Add a function in the country model

```
 public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('user');//or if there is no user_id column in the countries table, use the ('model','local_key','foreign_key') pattern.
 }
```

Then create an array with the country_ids, and que the country model.

```
 $country_ids=array(4,67);
 $countries=Country::where('id',$country_ids[0])->where('id',$country_ids[1])->get();
```

In order to get the users you should loop through like this

```
foreach($countries->user as $user)
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure for the result but you can var_dump($countries) and see what you get.

Comment: with the "whereIn" method, I'll get all those users who have one of the given countries, I'd like to get the users who have ALL the countries given

Comment: you are right. See my edit. you can chain your where()'s . that translates into WHERE something AND something_else