# How to get the max ID in a Join Query in Laravel 5 (Integrity constraint violation:)

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, has-many

**My query is like this:**

```
$deals=DB::table('leadsheet')
            ->join('Deal', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'Deal.leadcode')
             ->join('benefits', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'benefits.leadcode')
             ->join('delegatedealinfo', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'delegatedealinfo.leadcode')
              ->join('vipbooking', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'vipbooking.leadcode')
             ->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from vipbooking)"))
           ->where('leadsheet.leadcat', '=','Delegates')

            ->get();
```

**So I have following tables:**

```
1.leadsheet 
   -- leadcode
   -- leadcat
2.Deal
   -- leadcode
3.benefits
   -- leadcode
4.delegatedealinfo
   -- leadcode
5.vipbooking
   -- leadcode
```

What I'm trying to do is to get all the maximum id of `vipbooking` form where `leadcode` is same as all the `leadcode` FROM `leadsheet` WHERE `leadsheet`.`leadcat`=Delegates

My only problem is `MAX ID` for `vipbooking` form is not working

Can any one one help me out

**UPDATE1**

after applying the solution provided by @anant

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `leadsheet` inner join `Deal` on `leadsheet`.`leadcode` = `Deal`.`leadcode` inner join `benefits` on `leadsheet`.`leadcode` = `benefits`.`leadcode` inner join `delegatedealinfo` on `leadsheet`.`leadcode` = `delegatedealinfo`.`leadcode` inner join `vipbooking` on `leadsheet`.`leadcode` = `vipbooking`.`leadcode` where `id` = (select MAX(id) AS vipid from vipbooking) and `leadsheet`.`leadcat` = Delegates)
```

**Rephrasing Question**

I want to get the details of the vipbooking form for a Deal of a Delegate user , we can find if a Deal is Vendor or Delegate from Leadsheet table

Leadsheet

```
id | leadcode | leadcat

1  | DL2016012| Delegates
2  | DL2016013| Delegates
3  | VL2016001| Vendors
4  | VL2016002| Vendors
```

Deals

```
id | leadcode | DealAmount

1  | DL2016012| 123
2  | VL2016002| 1000
2  | DL2016013| 1200
```

vipbooking

```
    id | leadcode | date      | bookingtxt

    1  | DL2016012| 20-04-2016| xxx
    2  | DL2016012| 20-04-2016| dddd
    3  | VL2016012| 21-04-2016| ppp
    4  | DL2016013| 20-04-2016| xxx
    5  | DL2016013| 22-04-2016| dddd
```

So my Out put should have

```
 2 123 | Delegates| DL2016012| 20-04-2016| dddd
 5 1200| Delegates| DL2016013| 22-04-2016| dddd
```

Thanks

Comment: @Anant are you a Laravel dev ? , I would Like an answer to solve this using the RelationShip way adding method to the Models , It some how  perform faster but Still I am going to try this now.

Comment: @Anant I am getting some error I have updated my question with the error kindly have a look

Comment: @Anant yes id is there and I have also tried with adding back tick also it doesn't work

Comment: @Anant `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `leadsheet` inner join `Deal` on `leadsheet`.`leadcode` = `Deal`.`leadcode` inner join `benefits` on `leadsheet`.`leadcode` = `benefits`.`leadcode` inner join `delegatedealinfo` on `leadsheet`.`leadcode` = `delegatedealinfo`.`leadcode` inner join `vipbooking` on `leadsheet`.`leadcode` = `vipbooking`.`leadcode` where `id` = (select MAX(`vipbooking.id`) AS vipid from vipbooking) and `leadsheet`.`leadcat` = Delegates)`

Comment: @Anant Yes I did try that

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk can you help me out with this

Comment: Remove the ambiguity. Clarify which table's id you are selecting

Comment: So, vipbooking in this instance - and if Delegates is a string, wrap it in inverted commas.

Comment: @Vikram I would , but rephrase your question and tell us in simple words what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise it's hard to suggest any sensible solution.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I tried to rephrase the question please have a look on my question

Comment: @Vikram Hey, I meant something in human-language :) Forget the tables, max id etc, and say what you need like you'd say it to non-tech person.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I rephrased again have a look :) hope this time I am bit clear

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the two queries.

```
$vipBookingMaxId = DB::table('vipbooking')
        ->select(DB::raw("MAX(`id`) AS maxId"))
        ->get();
$maxId = (null != $vipBookingMaxId) ? $vipBookingMaxId->maxId : 0;
$dealsQuery = DB::table('leadsheet')
        ->join('Deal', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'Deal.leadcode')
        ->join('benefits', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'benefits.leadcode')
        ->join('delegatedealinfo', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'delegatedealinfo.leadcode')
        ->join('vipbooking', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'vipbooking.leadcode');

if ($maxId) {
    $dealsQuery->where('id', $vipBookingMaxId->maxId);
}

$deals = $dealsQuery->where('leadsheet.leadcat', '=', 'Delegates')->get();
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$deals=DB::table('leadsheet')
            ->join('Deal', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'Deal.leadcode')
             ->join('benefits', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'benefits.leadcode')
             ->join('delegatedealinfo', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'delegatedealinfo.leadcode')
              ->join('vipbooking', 'leadsheet.leadcode', '=', 'vipbooking.leadcode')
             ->where('leadsheet.id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from vipbooking)"))
           ->where('leadsheet.leadcat', '=','Delegates')

            ->get();
```

added `leadsheet.id`

Comment: i tried but i had to change the leedsheet.id to vipbooking.id bcoz I want the max id of that , But still I am getting only one result , although i should get two result , Still confused why this is happening